# Face recognition with Emgu CV

Tags: .net, opencv, face-recognition, emgucv

I need to get coordinates of facial features with `Emgu CV`. I know it is possible to train `Haar` classifier and it will recognize the objects, but I need exact coordinates, instead of squares with such objects.

For example, I must retrieve the coordinates of the left and right edges of the eye, instead of the square around it. How do I do so?

Answer (score 2):

**Detection** and **recognition** are different processes. What you want is a face detection, and you can learn how to do it by taking a look at [opencv doc](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/objdetect/cascade_classifier/cascade_classifier.html). You should also need experience on opencv, because you can get mass center or corners of the drawn rectangle (the output of detectMultiScale method) easily if you want to.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!
I doubt that I can get the exact coordinates because I see often illustrations like these: [link1](http://sj.vdelzen.net/wp-content/uploads/2011/05/opencv003.png), [link2](http://eclecti.cc/files/2008/03/face.jpg), [link3](http://2.bp.blogspot.com/_vx0BjlnaOso/S7XAp11nJbI/AAAAAAAAAdw/T4Xc1ZY_uMY/s400/face-detect+cropped.png).
These squares often contain an empty field (without face).

Comment: That square is a `Rect` structure of opencv; which has x, y ,width and height properties for you to use. For example, center of it is nothing but Point2f(Rect.x+Rect.width/2, Rect.y+Rect.height/2). For the eyes, check out the eye detector at the same link.

Comment: Yes, I understand. But in the first image(for example) width of the rectangle is not equal width of the face.

Comment: You can try [skin detector](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12968576/opencv-skin-detection) enhancement to cancel out non-face regions inside rectangles.

Comment: Thanks, and what can I do for detect facial features(for example nose)?

Comment: How [here](http://habrastorage.org/storage2/651/b48/dd3/651b48dd302163d7b296879cdfea6eba.png) got not a square, and rectangle?