# Skin / people detection in Java?

Tags: java, computer-vision

Does anyone know about any Java library or framework that could allow me to detect people in a picture (jpg, png, etc..)?

I don't need to detect faces, nor recognize them.

All I need to know is if there is a human being present in a picture (or not).

Comment: What do you need this for?  If you are look at a picture of the back of a person, should it work out this?

Comment: This is very vague. Do they have to have skin exposed? What if it is just part of a person (hand, leg, ect.)? What if it is a silhouette? What if it is an image of an image containing a person? These are all research questions that people work on for years, **not** something you ask on SO.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.

Comment: That said, I also recommend OpenCV. If you are doing this for commercial purpose, consider FaceVACS (it is very expensive but very high quality).

Comment: The goal is to make sure a user does not upload a picture that depicts a person to my web application. I need to allow only pictures of houses (interior/exterior), desert landscapes (city, country side, and so on ..)

Comment: May b this will help http://popscan.blogspot.in/2012/08/skin-detection-in-digital-images.html

Answer (score 2):

I used OpenCV for a project at university. It is open source and supports many different languages, also Java. Furthemore, it has a big user community.

http://opencv.org/

Comment: Here's someone doing similar things with OpenCV
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12968576/opencv-skin-detection

Comment: Thank you very much. If I don't find any pure Java solution I will check this project.

Answer (score 2):

Have you checked [Scholar.Google](http://scholar.google.com/)? This is a fairly common task in image processing research.

The methods that come to mind are:

- [Viola-Jones objects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viola%E2%80%93Jones_object_detection_framework) (based on [Haar cascades](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haar-like_features) and already implemented in [OpenCV](http://opencv.org/))
- Edge detection
- [Neural networks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artificial_neural_network)
- Human skin color (very naive)
- [Blob detection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blob_detection) (Matlab is good language for this)

Comment: Thank you very much. But I really need this to be pure Java. If I don't find any open source solution I'll have to start a project from scratch and then I'll use all the available literature as a basis for my implementation.